# javascript multiplication, addition and subtraction

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I'm trying to make an invoice but I have some problems. How cloud I get Amount, Subtotal and Return using javascript without clicking on a button? 
Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
[image: sample image]

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["product"] . "\n<input type='checkbox' name='product[" . $row['product_id'] . "]' value=" . $row["product_id"] . "></td>";         

     echo "<td>Quantity\n\n<select name='quantity[" . $row['product_id'] . "]'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
        <option value='6'>6</option>
        <option value='7'>7</option>
        <option value='8'>8</option>
        <option value='9'>9</option>
        <option value='10'>10</option>
    </select><br /></td>";

    echo "<td>Price <input type='text' name='price[" . $row['product_id'] . "]' value=" . $row["price"] . "></td>";
    echo "<td>Amount <input type='text' name='amount[" . $row['product_id'] . "]'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }
 }

?>
</table>
<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>Subtotal <input type="text" name="subtotal" size="10" /></td>
<td>Pay <input type="text" name="pay" size="10" /></td>
<td>Return <input type="text" name="return" size="10" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        function calculate() { var price = document.getElementById('price[" . $row['product_id'] . "]').value; 
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity[" . $row['product_id'] . "]').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('amount[" . $row['product_id'] . "]'); 
  var total = price * quantity;
  total.value = total; }
function {
  //get pay
  $('.pay').change(function(){
   var subtotal = $('.subtotal').val()-0;
   var get      = $(this).val()-0;
   $('.return').val(get - subtotal);
  });
}
</script>`

This javascript i'm using

Comment: call that function on page load or add it as a `change` event to all of those elements.